# Why does this page render with such a narrow table?

Tags: html

I'm using Django, and I had this working.  I must have broken it somehow.
The input fields should not all be the same length -- the house number field is about 1/3 the size of the others.  I'm seeing this narrow table on both FF and Gnome.

Here's the HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>anti-fracking initiative</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<h1>Packet # 1, signature # 3</h1>

<form action="/oil/1/3/" method="post">
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='<redacted>' />
<input type='hidden' name='phase' value='1' />
<table border="1" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0">
  <tr><th align="right">First Name:</th><td><input type="text" name="name_first" value="" id="name_first" maxlength="32" style="width:350"</td></tr>
  <tr><th align="right">Last Name:</th><td><input type="text" name="name_last" value="" id="name_first" maxlength="32" style="width:350"> </td></tr>
  <tr><th align="right">House Number:</th><td><input type="text" name="house_number" value="" id="house_number" maxlength="10" style="width:100"></td></tr>
  <tr><th align="right">Street:</th><td><input type="text" name="street" value="" id="street" maxlength="32" style="width:350"></td></tr>
  <tr><th align="right">City:</th><td><input type="text" name="city" value="" id="city" maxlength="32" style="width:350"></tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td align="right"><button type="reset" style="color:red"><strong>Reset</strong></button> <button type="submit" value="search" name="action" style="background-color:lightgreen" ><strong>Search</strong></button></td></tr>
</table>
</form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Width:100?  The rest of your inputs are set to 350

Comment: Well, yes.  But those other inputs are showing short.  As if they were all specified as 100.  Earlier, the number was short and the others were about 3 times as long.  That's what I want again.  And if I set them all 350, they're all still short, in spite of taking up only a fraction of my window., and less than the frame just above them (removed for brevity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot `px`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>anti-fracking initiative</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<h1>Packet # 1, signature # 3</h1>

<form action="/oil/1/3/" method="post">
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='<redacted>' />
<input type='hidden' name='phase' value='1' />
<table border="1" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0">
  <tr><th align="right">First Name:</th><td><input type="text" name="name_first" value="" id="name_first" maxlength="32" style="width:350px;"</td></tr>
  <tr><th align="right">Last Name:</th><td><input type="text" name="name_last" value="" id="name_first" maxlength="32" style="width:350px;"> </td></tr>
  <tr><th align="right">House Number:</th><td><input type="text" name="house_number" value="" id="house_number" maxlength="10" style="width:100px;"></td></tr>
  <tr><th align="right">Street:</th><td><input type="text" name="street" value="" id="street" maxlength="32" style="width:350px;"></td></tr>
  <tr><th align="right">City:</th><td><input type="text" name="city" value="" id="city" maxlength="32" style="width:350px;"></tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td align="right"><button type="reset" style="color:red"><strong>Reset</strong></button> <button type="submit" value="search" name="action" style="background-color:lightgreen" ><strong>Search</strong></button></td></tr>
</table>
</form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: <facepalm> yes I made a stupid beginner mistake </facepalm>  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the width of the  tag? Perhaps trying with width:100%?